# How to add Material Design on my app

Tags: java, android

I have a big problem.
With Eclipse (I have latest API and SDK of Android 5.0) I was trying to transform my app with material design. The problem is that Eclipse seems unable to recognize the code.
I'll try to be very detailed:
This is my principal code:

#### Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL = "http://178.32.137.180:8665/stream";

private ProgressBar playSeekBar;

private Button buttonPlay;

private Button buttonStopPlay;

private MediaPlayer player;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeUIElements();

    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

private void initializeUIElements() {

    playSeekBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    playSeekBar.setMax(100);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonPlay) {
        startPlaying();
    } else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
        stopPlaying();

    }
}

private void startPlaying() {
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    player.prepareAsync();

    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            player.start();
        }
    });

}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        initializeMediaPlayer();
    }

    buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
    playSeekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
    player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            playSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
            Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


}


};
```

#### Styles.xml on res/values

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular 
         API-level can go here. -->
</style>

</resources>
```

I was trying to follow this guide -> http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html but I'm blocked after the first point, the extension of activity into `ActionBarActivity` (done)...
Can I have some help? I only want to apply Material Design (black) to my app.. Someone can help me?
I'm a bit new in this part of android, so, be very detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add dependency in your project to `appcompatv7` library to support Material design on devices lover than SDK 5.0

Here are instructions how to setup `appcompat` library in eclipse: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

After that you need to define your theme as this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```

and all your activities to extend `ActionBarActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
}
```

Comment: Big problem xD If I use that guide, my project it s to delete and re-create from zero (and I have do this today :( )  it's like a curse._.  I want material design and effects but nothing... I fail..

Comment: Why do you need to recreate it from zero?

Comment: Correction : now I don't need to delete all, but if I extend my MainActivity into actionbaractivity (importing the Java appcompatv7 as the guide say), my app crash at start. .. and Eclipse didn't find material theme, if I modify the styles.xml... So, I need again a big help :/ I have tried around 4 times, also with new project :( but nothing..

Comment: When you extend `ActionBarActivity` you can't add Material theme. I have wrote in the answer, you need `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: Yes, and I change my style.xml with that voice, but also without change it, the app crash on start if I extend to actionbaractivity :/